# How to upload files through VPS to Ubuntu server using PuTTY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, ftp

I have my VPS pretty much set up now, and want to upload some basic files to the server, which is running Ubuntu 9.10. I am using my home laptop with Windows XP and connecting to the VPS with PuTTY. How can I upload the files? Is there any ftp program, like in regular managed hostings, to just upload files with? I was thinking about ProFTPd, but don't have a clue how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd install sshd (openssh) on the Ubuntu system (secure shell server) and then use something like filezilla to transfer the files securely over scp, or anything that supports sftp or scp to transfer them up to the server. Plain FTP sends passwords in cleartext, a definitely bad thing to do.

I'd also consider installing sshd and modifying it to listen to a custom port other than 22 to ward off automated attack scans, and make sure you have a good password as well as installing a package like denyhosts to block multiple incorrect passwords (be careful not to lock yourself out, go through the config file and whitelist your own ip if you need to).

Comment: Moving to a non-standard port is still security through obscurity.  Any port scanner will still catch it.  If you want to restrict access, use packet filtering.

Comment: It's not meant to stop people from finding that you're running it. It's meant to stop automated scans of SSH, and it's very effective against the largest portion of attacks out there as most of them are hardcoded to hit port 22. It's simply not efficient to hit every host and do a portscan for every port on every host an attacker wants to get. If someone wants to get your particular machine, no, it's not effective, and the denyhosts prevents brute force attacks, as I mentioned already in the answer.

Comment: It's not a good idea no matter how many times it's suggested.

Comment: @Warner: I moved it, my password attempts dropped to near nil. Once I had denyhosts in place, what few attempts I still had were reduced to nothing since it was pre-blocking IP's from other denyhost sites. I didn't put it in to make the system invulnerable, I put it there to reduce my attack surface, and the logs indicate it accomplished that. No more obscure than port knocking, it makes my system just less appetizing to script kiddies scanning for easy targets.

Comment: And as I already acknowledged, it is security through obscurity, but it was only meant to reduce automated attacks from filling my logs and it was never meant as an effective means of keeping determined, targeted attacks from finding it. If you're being targeted for an attack you have another problem to deal with.

Comment: Publicly recommending band aid solutions to novices is a good way to misrepresent a kluge as a best practice, that's my only concern.  Why not recommend packet filtering, port knocking, denyhosts, or portsentry instead?  Are those solutions less robust for preventing benign programmatic traffic?

Comment: I did put in denyhosts. The op is free to implement packet filtering if he'd like, I didn't recommend against it, and I didn't say port knocking simply because I hadn't implemented it (but am familiar with the technique) and I'd certainly consider that too. If anyone else knows why changing ports in addition to other techniques is bad, feel free to chime in. I find it a simple and effective way to reduce the attack profile, and the simpler I keep it the less trouble I've had down the road, and takes less resources to process than filtering rules (although even that is insignificant today)

Answer (score 2):

Bart Silverstrim's answer is good, you really don't want to install a plain FTP server on your VPS.

His recommendation of  [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is the same I'd recommended.  It's is primarily a scp/sftp client that added regular FTP/FTPS capabilities.  Or, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) which started as a FTP client, and later added scp, sftp & ftps capabilities.  (Note: sftp == an FTP-like protocol tunneled over ssh, FTPS == Regular port 21 FTP + SSL/TLS (on another port), both protect from password sniffing)

Since you pointed out your already connecting with SSH, and by default, openssh installs with the sftp server enabled, you have everything you need on the server to transfer files to and from it with these 2 programs.

Answer (score 2):

Putty comes with a secure FTP client called `psftp.exe`.  It allows file transfers using the SSH protocol.  You won't need an FTP server, the SSH server will do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any FTP. You have SSH access (I assume so, as you said you've configured it), that's enough. You can browse your server in e.g. nautilus, just type `ssh://servername` into the location bar. You can copy stuff with `scp` on the command line. You can even mount the filesystem on the server into your own using sshfs (there is a package on Debian/Ubuntu for it, named so). So why would you need an additional ftpd?

A note about SSH security: Best way is not to use passwords at all and authenticate with [Public Keys](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/), you also don't need the denyhosts stuff then.